# How can I improve code readability?

Tags: c, winsock

I know that the payoload of the function `send()` through winsocket is a pointer to an array of char, I want to use it to send a set of fixed values, I'd like to write something like this

```
send(socket, FIXED_VALUE_N, (int)strnlen(FIXED_VALUE), 0);
```

At the same time would be confortable for readibility and manteinance setting the couples (name,value) this way or similar (consider it a pseudocode):

```
FIXED_VALUE_1 <- 1
FIXED_VALUE_2 <- 2
FIXED_VALUE_3 <- 3
...
```

What can I use for? I've discarted enums since they are ints, and I consider a waste making four sends of one byte each. An alternative would be to define a macro, but I can't define a macro for a byte and not just a string, since I want to send '27', rather than '2','7'.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this stack is more appropriate : http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Have you considered concatenating your data _strings_ into comma separated groups?  This would allow multiple pairs to be sent, and parsed on the receive side.

Comment: Hm. `strnlen` takes two args, just a heads up.

Comment: You can also write a macro to turn your number around quotes.

Comment: Something like `#define FIXED_VALUE_N "123"`? Doesn't is it a string of 3 bytes?

Comment: Don't forget the NULL byte at the end.  It would be a char array (string) of 4 bytes:  |1|2|3|\0|.  But it would look like "123"  (NULL byte is not seen in most presentations.  I use a debugger if I want to view them.)

Comment: Yes, you're right. What I mean is that's what I'm trying to avoid to do: sending many bytes when one is just enough.

Comment: The most efficient way I know to send or receive data via any method is to use blocks of byte data, which you are doing if you are using char data types.  An array of char, is an array of byte data.  Define `char bytedata[100];` (or what ever size you need).  Populate it with the appropriate byte values and send it.  See EDIT 2 in my answer below.

Comment: @Daniele - please give an explicit example of what it is you would _like_ to send...  Keep in mind, if you use `send()`, it definition requires you use char * (array):   int `send(
  _In_  SOCKET s,
  _In_  const char *buf,
  _In_  int len,
  _In_  int flags
);`

Comment: @ryyker, Sorry if my question wasn't clear enough. I know how to use send() to send my byte, the problem is more about syntactic sugar, eg.: `const byte ESC_PFX = 0x1B; send( ConnectSocket, &ESC_PFX, (int)strlen(ESC_PFX), 0 );` works. `#define ESC_PFX "\x1B"; send( ConnectSocket, ESC_PFX, (int)strlen(ESC_PFX), 0 );` does not.

Comment: See the edit 3 in answer, toward top of post.

Answer (score 4):

First, note that as written,

```
send(socket, FIXED_VALUE_N, (int)strnlen(FIXED_VALUE_N), 0);  
                                                    ^^ //added to correct typo
```

FIXED_VALUE_N would have to be in the form of const char * to be correct.  And, `strnlen()` requires two arguments, (second is `size_t number_of_elements`).

***EDIT 3***  (addressing latest comment question)

If you declare and populate FIXED_VALUE_N as:

```
const char FIXED_VALUE_N[2];
FIXED_VALUE_N[0]=0x1B;
```

As well as correct the syntax of the third argument...

```
send(socket, FIXED_VALUE_N, 1, 0); //hard-coded third argument for illustration
```

...It will work because you are now passing a pointer to const char  (`const char *`)  in the second argument, and complying with syntax requirements of the `send()` prototype.
***(end EDIT 3)***

With that in mind, have you considered concatenating your data strings into comma separated groups? This would allow multiple values to be sent, and parsed on the receive side.   Something such as:

```
#define MAX_SIZE 100 //pick a value that makes sense for your application, I randomly picked 100
char buffer[MAX_SIZE];
int len=0;

sprintf(buffer, "%d,%d,%d", FIXED_VALUE_1, FIXED_VALUE_2,FIXED_VALUE_3);
len = strlen(buffer); //****
send(socket, buffer, len + 1, 0);  // strlen() does not include `\0` byte in its return
                                   // value.  Use `len +1` to make room for 
                                   // \0 terminator - added by the sprintf() function.
```

Would send `"1,2,3"`

Regarding your statement:  *since I want to send '27', rather than '2','7'.*

Leave the commas out of the formatting `sprintf()` statement, and the numbers you sent will be consecutive.

```
sprintf(buffer, "%d%d%d", FIXED_VALUE_1, FIXED_VALUE_2,FIXED_VALUE_3);
                 ^^^^^^
```

Would send `"123"`

***EDIT***  (populate len using return of sprintf)
Also, as pointed out by @Jack:
Instead of using `strlen()`, you can save a line of code by simply setting len = sprintf(...); on the line above.  (see `****` in code snippet above) 
as `sprintf()` returns the *number of characters transmitted* or a negative value if an output error occurred. 
(if output is negative, error occurred)

***EDIT 2***  (byte data, per your comment above)

If you want to send data in the smallest (most efficient) form factor, use byte data.  byte data can be stored in a char array:

```
char *byte_data=0;

byte_data = malloc(NUM_BYTES_RQD);//#define NUM_BYTES_RQD as needed, 
                                  //or pass in size info as an argument 
                                  //from calling function  

//populate byte_data

for(i=0;<NUM_BYTES_RQD;i++)
{
    byte_data[i]=<enter byte value here>
}
send(socket, byte_data, len, 0);  
free(byte_data);
```

Comment: `sprintf()` return the number of bytes written in buffer so you may use it instead of `strlen(buffer)`

Comment: My point wasn't just about save a line of code but peformance. If you can avoid compute exactly same value twice (or mode), you shouldn't do.

Comment: @Jack - agreed.  Performance increase was assumed by _save a line of code_ :)

Comment: Without sending the `'\0'`, how does the receiving end know when the content of one `send()` ends and another begins?  Consider `send(socket, buffer, len + 1, 0);` or append a comma.

Comment: @chux -   Thanks.  Added that, and commented.  But important to note: `recv() methods vary greatly depending on implementation of protocols using them.  I have used protocols where a particular series of bytes indicated the end of a data block.  So I don't think it _always_ necessary to include a \0 to terminate byte data.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using [the X macro?](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-new-c-x-macros/184401387)

```
#define X(a, b) a,

#define FIXED_VALUES_TABLE
X(FIXED_VALUE_1, "1") \
X(FIXED_VALUE_2, "2") \
// ...

enum { FIXED_VALUES_TABLE };
#undef x

#define X(a, b) b,
const char *fixed_values_values[] = { FIXED_VALUES_TABLE };
#undef x
```

And then you can use like this:

```
char *val = fixed_values_values[FIXED_VALUE_1];
char *va2 = fixed_values_values[FIXED_VALUE_2];
```

if you want to concat them, you can use `malloc()+strcat()`.

Comment: I had not heard of that.  Very nice.